# VBA to filter data as you type (numbers)

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

How can this solution be modified to work with numbers? As for now it only works if the filtering phrase is text.

http://chandoo.org/wp/2015/08/22/filter-as-you-type-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps that the link did and then use the following code replacing the Range("$B$4:$B$5000") sections with the actual data you want to filter. This also assumes that you are linking the Text Box to Cell A1.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & CStr(Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value) & ""

End Sub
```

Additionally you may want to get all values that contain that integer in the number and you could use the following (although considerably slower)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
vCheck = CStr(Range("A1").Value)
For Each vCell In Range("B5:B5000")
vValue = CStr(vCell.Value)
If Not CBool(InStr(1, vValue, vCheck, vbBinaryCompare)) Then
hideRow = vCell.Row
Rows(hideRow).Hidden = True
Else
hideRow = vCell.Row
Rows(hideRow).Hidden = False
End If
Next vCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works as expected if data range is in one column. Can this solution be adopted to data in several columns with only one Text Box?

Comment: You could do this by having a single column with an if statement looking at multiple columns and filtering on that combined column. i.e. if A = 2 or B = 2 Then 1 Else 0 and filter only for values in column C (the if statement) that have a value of 1 (i.e. meeting the condition that you have set)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later. Much appreciated.

Comment: So you can use the following if statement in column D, "= IF(XOR(IF(B5=$A$1,1,0),IF(C5=$A$1,1,0))=TRUE, 1, 0)" and Filter on B4:D5000. Then set the Criteria="1" and use Field = 3 in the VBA code